# Joining after join with yq

Tags: bash, yq

I have the following structure in yml:

```
metadata:
  name: nws-bot
  version: 0.1.0
  jobs:
  - name: name1
    script: job1.sh
    schedule: 0 20 * * *
  - name: name2
    script: job2.sh
    schedule: 0 22 * * *
```

I'm trying to create a structure like this:

```
name1~job1.sh;name2~job2.sh
```

The job name and script are separated by a ~, and the jobs are separated by a ;.

I can get this to work using

```
yq '.metadata.jobs[] | [[.name, .script] | join("~")]' project.yml | yq '. | join(";")'
```

However I wonder if it can be done with a single `yq`expression, instead of piping to `yq` a second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating with `.metadata.jobs[]` (which is a shortcut for `.metadata.jobs | .[]`) also destructures the array into its individual items. To re-capture them (meanwhile modified with the first `join`) back into an array (to be applied to the second `join`) necessitates the collecting array to be superordinate to the destructuring. Thus, move the iteration inside of it, i.e. pull the opening bracket up front (with the initial traversal to `.metadata.jobs` included or excluded at your preference):

```bash
yq '.metadata.jobs[] | [[.name, .script] | join("~")]' project.yml | yq 'join(";")'
#   ╭──────────────────╯
yq '[.metadata.jobs[] | [.name, .script] | join("~")] | join(";")' project.yml
#   ╰────────────────╮
yq '.metadata.jobs | [.[] | [.name, .script] | join("~")] | join(";")' project.yml
```

Actually, having `[.[] | …]` is what `map(…)` does: applying a filter to the items of an array while retaining the array structure. Using named filters can make code more descriptive and facilitate its readability. Alternatively, there's also the update operator `|=` which can be used to alter the items of a (generally deeper) structure without destructuring it. In both cases, however, your context here needs to be the array itself, so the initial traversal to `.metadata.jobs` must be completed prior to their usage (e.g. `.metadata.jobs[] |= …` would in excess also retain the top level objects, making the second `join` eventually fail).

```bash
yq '.metadata.jobs | map([.name, .script] | join("~")) | join(";")' project.yml
# or
yq '.metadata.jobs | .[] |= ([.name, .script] | join("~")) | join(";")' project.yml
```

Given your sample input, all of them output:

```
name1~job1.sh;name2~job2.sh
```